# Include "area" in 3 columns in InDesign (merging part of columns)

Tags: adobe-indesign, tables

I've been trying to accomplish in InDesign something along the attached screenshot.

I've a 3-columns indesign file and will like to add a block (either an image or a table) like the one in the attached example.

I'm trying to find for an automated (or relatively simple) solution as I will have to add it in many places along a biiiiggggg file and would like to try and avoid any method that requires a lot of manual modifications.

[image: Example]

Comment: Your question is gaining close votes as it's a bit unclear what you are asking. If I understand you correctly there are different ways to accomplish what you want. Either have those blocks in separate frames with [text wrap](https://helpx.adobe.com/indesign/using/text-wrap.html) or apply [span columns](https://helpx.adobe.com/uk/indesign/using/aligning-text.html) to the paragraphs you want to take up more than one column. If you use the last solution you need to know about [anchored objects](https://helpx.adobe.com/indesign/using/anchored-objects.html) too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **Text Wrap** feature in InDesign works great for this:

As its name suggests it allows you to specify how you want text to wrap around objects (other text frames, images, shapes) that you place over an existing text frame.

[image: The Text Wrap Panel]

You can find it here:  <kbd>Windows</kbd>/ <kbd>Text Wrap</kbd>